# Design event view using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

i want to make a view for event details, using swift, something like this one:

[image]

what do you suggest me to use? tableview? collectionview? every events has a different numbers of rows and every row can have a different height, example based on text.

Is there some example on the web?

Thanks!

Comment: tableview will be better

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a tableView and everything row should be in section.

1. Sections:

   - image section
   - action section
   - date section

and so for forward. For the sections you can use and enum so you don't use directly ints. Then every section has one row usually. The final design should result pretty clean.